# Openpyxl lowercase VLOOKUP

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am working on a script to help my boss modify `.xlsx` files that he gets. I'm trying to insert a `VLOOKUP` into every cell in a column, but I am running into an issue where some of the letters inside the parenthesis are being changed to lowercase.

This is the code I am using:

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('wb.xlsx')
ws = wb['Sheet1']

for row in ws['J1:J847']:
    for cell in row:
        cell.value = '=VLOOKUP(A{0}, Collection.A:G,7,0)'.format(cell.row)

wb.save('test.xlsx')
```

The output in the spreadsheet is:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1, collection.a:g,6,0)
```

I need it to look like:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1, Collection.a:g,6,0)
```

or even better:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1, Collection.A:G,6,0)
```

I have checked to ensure that the string is being formatted correctly. What I find most confusing is that not all of the `uppercase` characters are being switched. What am I doing wrong and what is happening under the covers to cause something like this?

Comment: Is that your code in its entirety? I get the exact same string trying to reproduce your issue.

By the way you have a typo in the last line of code, should be `wb.save('test.xlsx')` and not `wb.save['test.xlsx']`

Comment: No, it isn't my code in its entirety, but it is enough to replicate the issue I am having. I have tested this snippet repeatedly on blank, and populated, spreadsheets, the results stay the same. If you are getting the correct result, I am wondering if I am using the wrong version of something. I am running Python 3.6.5 and below is the contents of my requirements.txt.
et-xmlfile==1.0.1
jdcal==1.4
openpyxl==2.5.4
pkg-resources==0.0.0

Comment: Do you have autocorrect turned on? Common for Word, but can be turned on for Excel and is notorious for this sort of thing.

Comment: @DavKle132, Ah, I've checked it on Python 2.7, openpyxl 2.5.1 so might be different.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu so I have LibreOffice to view the spreadsheets. I turned off all auto-replace utilities, but I am not too familiar with LibreOffice.

Comment: What version of openpyxl did you use to get the correct output @droravr? I want to check the changelogs to see what the issue might be.

Comment: @DavKle132, Just updated and checked on 2.5.4, seems to work for me as well.

Comment: This may have something to do with LibreOffice. I ran the same code on my Windows machine that is also running python 3.6.5 and openpyxl 2.5.4 and I got the correct results. The only difference is that I opened the spreadsheet in Excel.

Comment: I have moved my development over to my Windows machine that is running Excel. While I haven't found a definite answer, I am confident that the issue is with how LibreOffice reads and interprets `xlsx` files because they are not the native file structure to Calc. Also, thank you for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and it was fixed by replacing the period by an exclamation point.

```
=VLOOKUP(A{0}, Collection!A:G,7,0)
```